# nouveau fifo CACHE_ERROR in dmseg

Tags: drivers, nvidia, lubuntu, nouveau

Hello dear community member.
I have already installed Lubuntu on an old computer, that I use in my laboratory. From a few days ago, it needs about one minute or more to boot. When I checked dmesg, it returns a fulfilled screen with this error:

```
[   58.042951] nouveau 0000:01:00.0: fifo: CACHE_ERROR - ch 0 [DRM] subc 3 mthd 0dd8 data 00000000
[   58.042964] nouveau 0000:01:00.0: fifo: CACHE_ERROR - ch 0 [DRM] subc 3 mthd 0ddc data 00000000
[   58.042977] nouveau 0000:01:00.0: fifo: CACHE_ERROR - ch 0 [DRM] subc 3 mthd 0de0 data 00000000
[   58.042989] nouveau 0000:01:00.0: fifo: CACHE_ERROR - ch 0 [DRM] subc 3 mthd 0de4 data 00000000
```

and so one...

this is my graphic card:

```
01:00.0 VGA compatible controller: NVIDIA Corporation NV18 [GeForce4 MX 440 AGP 8x] (rev a2) (prog-if 00 [VGA controller])
    Subsystem: Micro-Star International Co., Ltd. [MSI] NV18 [GeForce4 MX 440 AGP 8x]
    Flags: bus master, 66MHz, medium devsel, latency 32, IRQ 16
    Memory at e8000000 (32-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=16M]
    Memory at e4000000 (32-bit, prefetchable) [size=64M]
    [virtual] Expansion ROM at 000c0000 [disabled] [size=128K]
    Capabilities: [60] Power Management version 2
    Capabilities: [44] AGP version 3.0
    Kernel driver in use: nouveau
    Kernel modules: nvidiafb, nouveau
```

I'll become so appreciate if you can help me. I'm wondering if this cause slow booting? Is it an important error? What should I do?!

thanks for your time.

edit:

oops! it seems system randomly restarts too!

Perhaps you should be informed about that I've changed my CPU from Celeron to Pentium recently.

Comment: No, it doesn't slow the boot process and are mostly harmless. The proprietary Nvidia driver likely wouldn't have this problem but it's no longer available for hardware of that vintage.

Comment: I see no release details; which are the best indication of what software stack you're using (though LTS releases have two kernel stack choices; default selected by the ISO used to install a Lubuntu system, but you've given no details). Switching from the GA to the more modern HWE kernel stack can help, or for some really old devices the GA stack can perform better; but we currently don't know your release details.

Comment: @guiverc I'm using lubuntu 18.04 i386 LTS. I realized problem is emerge when I use Pentium4 658! but there isn't any problem with Celeron.

Comment: FYI:  Lubuntu 18.04 LTS is no longer supported; refer https://lubuntu.me/bionic-eol/ or https://fridge.ubuntu.com/2020/08/14/ubuntu-18-04-5-lts-released/ where you'll note only Ubuntu Server, Ubuntu Desktop & Ubuntu Cloud come with 5 years of support; *flavors* had shorter lives. I'd suggest using `ubuntu-support-status` to assess the security status of your actual install. Your question is still on-topic here, but consider how much security matters to you and the results of prior command. You're now using Ubuntu 18.04 LTS with LXDE (*not Lubuntu*).

Comment: If the system *randomly restarts* I'd evaluate the hardware looking for problems, starting with PSU, motherboard, ram, ... and of course CPU given you changed it prior to issues.  I had no issues with pentium 4 boxes QA-testing (up to 19.04; some graphic glitches on *eoan* but that was GPU related), some pentium M boxes did better with GA kernel stack, no issue with single celeron x86-only box)